# How to get "r_fullprofile" application permission for an academic project?

Tags: linkedin-api

We are currently working on an application as part of our final year project at our University. Application is relevant to talent acquisition and we need r_fullprofile permission for our LinkedIn developer application to access some of our test user's skills. Does LinkedIn allow students to have that access for academic purpose?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For full profile permission, you must apply to become a LinkedIn Partner.

Partner Program Application Form: https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/apply

2 or 3 weeks after making the application will return the answer.

Good lucks